# Why my ajax function does not work on yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, chart.js

Hello *** please How can i use ajax function in yii2

in fact I am working on a product of this framework(yii2), not on it directly, But I think it's the same principle. and i want to draw charts (chartJs or googleChart or d3 ... anyway)

so in index file of backend area (xx/xx/xx/dashboard/index.php) I want to send an ajax request to an another php file (simple and logical)

this one is placed in the same folder as index (xx/xx/xx/dashboard) ,  but nothing happens ! :(

I notice that if I test my two files (indexAjax and phpDB) outside framework folders I get a nice result
but once it's has within framework files, they will no longer work :(

my code is as follows :
1/ part of my index file

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
$(function()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "chartData.php",
  type:'POST',
  data:{'trigger':'trigger'},
  success: function(data) {
   
   alert(data);
   console.log(data);
   var idTab = [];
   var resultatTab = [];

   for(var i in data) {
    idTab.push("data " + data[i].id);
    resultatTab.push(data[i].resultat);
   }

   var chartdata = {
    labels: idTab,
    datasets : [
     {
      label: 'Player Score',
      backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue',
      borderColor: 'dodgerblue',
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'orange',
      hoverBorderColor: 'yellow',
      data: resultatTab
     }
    ]
   };

   var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

   var doughnutGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: chartdata,
    options:{responsive:false}
   });
  },
  error: function(data) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
}); // fin jQuery
</script>
```

2/ the 2nd file (php)

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['trigger']))
{
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'lab');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM score");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
 
}
```

NB: I must also say that I did not respect the principle of the MVC
i put everything in a same folder ... but I think it's still a choice

thanks a lot

Comment: Please try after setting full url of this file `url: "chartData.php",`

Comment: Maybe `method:'POST'` instead `type:'POST'`?

Comment: thank you for your answer
I already tried that without success ...i get an error in browser console :
http://127.0.0.1/sendmail/customer/dashboard/chartData.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I must also say that I did not respect the principle of the MVC i put everything in a same folder

but I think it's still a choice

Comment: just move the `header('Content-Type: application/json');` near to `print json_encode($data);` . There is a chance in db connection, query error etc. Also check htaccess, file permission etc.

Comment: no user6838959 it does not work ..thanks anyway 
no gre_gor ... it sould be type  not method !

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to look how the routing in yii2 works
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-overview.html
or here
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-hello.html

you can not directly call an php file ..

for example, in javascript:

```
$.get('/site/user-messages', function (data, status) {

                        if (status !== 'success') {
                                console.log('ERROR: '+ status);
                                return;
                        }
                        allData = JSON.parse(data);

});
```

here *site* is the **controller** and *user-messages* is the **action**
in this case the prettyUrl mode is enabled in urlManager

Comment: thank you Thomas Rohde ... i feel your answer will help me a lot

I'm going to follow your advice

Answer (score 1):

Add the content of you charData.php files in a proper action eg: inside siteController.php

```
 public function actionChartData() {
    your code 
    .........

    return $this->render('your_related_view', [
         /* your  vars */
        'my_var' => $my_var,
    ]);
}
```

the call the action i ajax using

```
$.ajax({
url: <?php echo   \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/site/chart-data']) ?>,
type:'POST',
data:{'trigger':'trigger'},
success: function(data) {
        ........
```